# HTTP post appends null to the request data ionic

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, ionic3

I have this data coming from form using

`<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="myFunction(form.value)">`

I am sending the form value to HTTP post method as

```
myFunction(formData){
   let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    });
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      this.http.post(this.my_api, formData, { headers: headers})
        .subscribe( data => {
          resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

When i console the *form.data*, i get

`{name: 'myname', address:'myaddress'}`

But
what i get in the api is

`{{"name":"myname", "address":"myaddress"} : null }`

which is making me hard to get the values in my backend.

**P.S. I am using Laravel as Backend**

Why is that *: null* is getting appended to the request?
How to get the values in the Laravel backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode the form data and then send that to the API call

```
 getFormUrlEncoded(formData) {
        const formBody = [];
        for (const property in toConvert) {
            const encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
            const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(toConvert[property]);
            formBody.push(encodedKey + '=' + encodedValue);
        }
        return formBody.join('&');
    }
```

then call the function

```
this.http.post(this.my_api, this.getFormUrlEncoded(formData), { headers: headers})
        .subscribe( data => {
          resolve(data);
        });
    });
```